# Getting the Total value from the Nett

Tags: calculator

I can't figure out this formula; I need some help to write it out for a php script.

> I have a value of $\$80$.
>
> $\$80$ is the profit from a total sale of $\$100$; $ 20\%$ is the percentage margin for the respective product.
>
> Now I just have the $\$80$ and want to get the total figure of $\$100$. How can I get the total figure and what would be the formula?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you get $80$ from $100$ after a $20$ per cent discount and want to reverse the process, multiply by $\frac{100}{100-20}=\frac{5}{4}$. The formula you need is $y=\frac{5x}{4}$, so if $x=80$, then $y=100$.

Comment: Awesome, you just solved and made my day, thank you so much. It worked perfectly.